# how to update live site

Tags: sql, wordpress, live

I have a website on a live server, it is a wordpress site. I got it to the live server by zipping the wordpress files, putting it in public_html cPanel and exporting the SQL database, then I created new database live server, imported the SQL database in and modified the wp_config file to reflect database name, user name and password.

My question is , if updating the site in the future how to do this. Would I need to overwrite all the wordpress files in public_html. Also what about the SQL database?

Thanks,

Comment: updates are text replamcement on the php files and updates to the database, so no problem there, but a s always ake a backup regularly and before any update

Comment: Wordpress core, plugins and theme's updates are handled by their authors and done directly in your admin dashboard. If you are talking about your own custom code changes in the files, then you should look into version control (svn, git) and deploy only the files that have been changed. The database should not be touched when updating code because it contains the latest data of your website.